# JavaFX HTMLEditor text changed in 5 seconds

Tags: java, javafx

I've come up with a problem that I'm having trouble finding out how to solve. I got a HtmlEditor event which detects when a key is pressed, but I need to create a listener to check if the HtmlEditor text was changed, and I came up with this:

```
htmlEditor.setOnKeyPressed((keyEvent) ->{
                            if(keyEvent.getCode().isDigitKey() || keyEvent.getCode().isLetterKey() ||
                            keyEvent.getCode().isModifierKey() || keyEvent.getCode().isWhitespaceKey() ||
                            keyEvent.isShiftDown()){
                                handleWhoTypes(null);     
                            }  
                        });

                        PauseTransition timer = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(5));
                        htmlEditor.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) ->
                            timer.playFromStart());
                        timer.setOnFinished(e -> handleIsPaused(null));
        }
```

But this won't work because the the htmlEditor doesn't have textProperty() and I cannot think of another solution. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you’ll have to poll the editor’s text:

```
Runnable textMonitor = new Runnable() {
    private String previousText;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String newText = htmlEditor.getHtmlText();
        boolean changed = !newText.equals(previousText);

        previousText = newText;

        if (changed) {
            timer.playFromStart();
        }
    }
};

BooleanBinding windowShowing = Bindings.selectBoolean(
    htmlEditor.sceneProperty(), "window", "showing");
windowShowing.addListener(
    new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        private ScheduledExecutorService executor;

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> o,
                            Boolean old,
                            Boolean showing) {
            if (showing) {
                executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
                executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
                    () -> Platform.runLater(textMonitor),
                    1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } else {
                executor.shutdown();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Right, I'll text it tomorrow. But there's one thing missing there, how do I call the method handleIsPaused() when those 5 seconds are over?

Comment: You can call `timer.setOnFinished` anywhere you want.  The above code is only concerned with starting the animation.

Comment: It didn't worked. After it's finished it should go to another method but it never goes into it.

Comment: When it gets to windowShowing.addListener it just leaves the rule and goes to a line below everything else.